Is this the right approach to ECS?
This is how I've designed my entity class. Instead of just an id, I made it a whole class:
#pragma once
#include "raylib.h"
#include <functional>
#include <list>

class Entity2D {
public:
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    Vector2 position;
    float rotation;
    float scale;
    Color tint;
    bool destroy;
    int id;
    static int nextId;
    std::function<void()> customUpdate2D;
    Entity2D(const char* texture_path, Vector2 position, float rotation, float scale, Color tint, std::function<void()> customUpdate=NULL);
    ~Entity2D();
    void destroyEntity2D();
    void drawEntity2D();
    void updateEntity2D();
};
class EntityManager {
public:
    std::list<Entity2D*> entities2D;
    void registerEntity(Entity2D* entity);
    void unregisterEntity(Entity2D* entity);
};

This approach is inspired by Ursina engine (an engine powered by Python and Panda3D).
Then, I saw a question on StackOverflow: Entity System in C++. I feel like that approach is just so flexible, but I also feel that mine is easier to use.
Can someone give me an advice about which approach I should use?

This does not look like an Entity Component System to me, at least from the code you've shown here. We can't see any components or systems. It looks like you intend to provide custom behaviour to each Entity2D by providing different function pointers for their customUpdate2D (a version of the Strategy Pattern), rather than by composing component instances. That could be fine - maybe you don't actually need an ECS for your game, or don't like working with it - but those assessments are ones that only you can make. We can't tell you how to make your game, but we can help you solve problems.

ilove working ecs thats why i made. but maybe the Ursina engine ecs is different so I have gotten a wrong concept of ecs?

If you're referring to this UrsinaECS, I don't see any equivalents in your code to the add_component() method shown there. How do you propose to compose multiple behaviours on one entity using this code?

Ursina already had an entity class but that might be a good resource for me. Thx u!

Note that not everything with an "Entity" class is an Entity Component System. The fact that someone made a separate ECS implementation for Ursina is a good clue that Ursina's built-in approach is not an ECS. The absence of components is another clue. That's OK, you're not required to use ECS / components, and ECS won't automatically make your game or game development "better". So, to refocus this question: is the code you've shared serving the role you need it to? Or are you experiencing any problems or limitations with it that Answers here can help you overcome?

i feel like the entity class of ursina make my development process faster and cleaner with me so i want to make one for raylib. Because of its high performance and ease of use.

Sounds like a good goal. What do you need from us? Is the code above doing what you need, or can we help you improve it in some way?

I love the link that you shared. I would love to learn more about ECS. The code about is good enough in order for it to work like Ursina engine, but i would like to explore more about ecs so i can build it more consistently. Thx for your dedication!
